# History of "novelty" to refer to dessert items

Tags: etymology, history

The word *novelty* can be used to refer to hand-held desserts, such as ice cream sandwiches or ice pops. What is the history of this usage? Presumably the etymology is straightforward, but what is the first recorded usage and when did it become common parlance?

I found [this link](https://www.thenibble.com/reviews/main/ice-cream/the-history-of-ice-cream7.asp) where the 1920s is referred to as when ice cream novelties were born, but there is no evidence there that the word was used at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Etymonline suggests that [novelty:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/novelty)

> sense of "useless but decorative or amusing object" is attested by 1888 (as in novelty shop, by 1893).

from which by extension it was probably used also to refer to packaged  ice creams, something really new for those days.

The following extract is from [The National Druggist](https://books.google.it/books?id=bW7nAAAAMAAJ&q=%22ice%20cream%20novelty%22&dq=%22ice%20cream%20novelty%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9pLGjjP7oAhXBrIsKHW3jBM8Q6AEITjAG) (1916)

> But the point remains that if a lady or a child would rather have an attractive ice cream novelty than the same quantity of cream served in a cone-shaped mass, it may be that there is an opportunity here to attract some business ...